# draw borderline around UITableView section in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have an issue regarding the section border. I have a `UITableView` and it is of type Grouped. I am trying to draw the border around the each section of the tableview. I am getting the section frame using the below code. Could please tell me how to draw the border around the `UITableView` section.

```
CGRect rect = [groupsTableView rectForSection:indexPath.section];

NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f",rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
```

[image]

Comment: Under section of UITableView do you mean UITableViewCell???

Comment: No. Draw around the whole section but not to the each tableviewcell in section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend that you make a new TableView Cell and inside this newTableViewCell, load all the cells in section 2 then give border to newTableViewCell.

but if you don't wanna do that then you can use this code :

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) CAShapeLayer* borderPath;

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
[_borderPath removeFromSuperlayer];
UIView *viewToGiveBorder = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:sectionView.frame];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:viewToGiveBorder.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerAllCorners) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

//apply path to shapelayer
_borderPath= [CAShapeLayer layer];
_borderPath.path = path.CGPath;
[_borderPath setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[_borderPath setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0 blue: 0].CGColor];
_borderPath.frame=sectionView.frame;

//add shape layer to view's layer
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:_borderPath];
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. We cannot load multiple tableviewcells in one tableviewcell

Comment: you can load multiple tableViewCells in one tableViewCell by putting a tableView inside tableViewCell and delegate all the methods of tableView in that cell.

Comment: or you can use the second method.

Comment: These are the methods i found for giving the border to the section, I am not sure there is any other way.

Comment: I have searched a lot and couldn't find any.Could you please tell me what are those methods

Comment: I already wrote the code for second method in case you don't like first one.In  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews, sectionView is the section you want to give border to.